# Flex popup window not covered the entire application after changing height of swf

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

In my Flex application I need to increase height of swf through javascript:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.height += 50;
ExternalInterface.call("changeMyAppHeight",FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.height);
```

After that I need to show popup window:

```
var modalPopUp:ModalPopUp= new ModalPopUp;
PopUpManager.addPopUp(modalPopUp, DisplayObject(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication), true);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(modalPopUp);
```

This modal window is not covered the whole application. There is a 50px gap in the bottom of my application which is not covered, thus, user can click some objects placed on this gap.

Is there a way to fix it?

I saw the same issue with Alert popup here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-27667
and here
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-30613

But it seems it was resolved more that 1 year ago.

I have the same issue when I opened an Alert window instead of Popup Manager modal window.

For my application I am using Flash Builder 4.6 and sdk 4.5.1

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Addition:
I have figured out that

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
```

affects Pop-up window covering functionality:
If I comment this line then Popup works correctly but in case if user press CTRL+mouseWheel in order to zoom in/out content in browser window then swf-application is not zooming properly. So, I need `StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL` in my code.

Comment: Did you set your top main container (`Application`) to `height="100%"`?

Comment: Yes, I have set height="100%", but it still the same.

Comment: try sdk v 4.6.0 it will not affect min. flash player version

Comment: Alex, issue is still replicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, this issue is not resolved yet:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-24140
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-26623